# JS - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I can't find the right answer on my problem please I need help I trying to make a dynamic markers from mysql and display it on the map currently I used the latIn from the database. Im pass the data from mysql to the function initMap parameter and tried to loop it so it will display the markers dynamically on the map.

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCysW8SYjBdZlZa91kpUCV3VQBEm3EQGgE&callback=initMap" type="text/javascript"></script>

$.ajax({
             url: "Gmap.aspx/GetLocationLatIn",
             data: "",
             dataType: "json",
             type: "POST",
             contentType: "application/json; chartset=utf-8",
             success: function (data) {
                 locationLatIn = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data.d));
                 var holder = [];
                 var allLocations = "";
                 for (var i = 0; i < $(locationLatIn).toArray().length; i++) 
                 {
                 holder.push(locationLatIn[i].locationLatInData.toString());
                 }
                 initMap(holder);
             }
         });

     })
     function initMap(holder) {

         var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
             zoom: 13,
             center: new google.maps.LatLng(14.6362904, 121.027754),
             mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
         });

         var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

         var marker, i;
         for (i = 0; i < holder.length; i++) { //Im getting an Error here saying that holder is undefined so the property length cant be read.
             marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                 position: new google.maps.LatLng(holder, 121.027754),
                 map: map
             });

             google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'hover', (function 
             (marker, i) {
                 return function () {
                     infowindow.setContent('Name');
                     infowindow.open(map, marker);
                 }
             })(marker, i));
         }
```

Comment: where is `initMap` called?

Comment: Edited: Sorry forgot to copy but it is already there, kindly check it now? thank you . Its on the parameter of the script

Comment: Seems more likely your error would be from `$(locationLatIn).toArray().length`

Comment: When I'm trying to run its indicating that it is on the holder.length in the for loop in the initMap function. But i'll check it. thank you for the answer

Answer (score 0):

`$(locationLatIn).toArray().length` - probably you are getting error at this point.
Check in the console the value of `$(locationLatIn)`

Also, why are you stringyfying and parsing the data.id.

Will it returns element tag, or element ID, etc. What is that you are trying to access.

Comment: Here is the log in the console of $(locationLatIn): Array(33)
0
:
{__type: "PrincipalPortal.Gmap+LocationsLatIn", locationLatInData: "37.421998333333335"}
1
:
{__type: "PrincipalPortal.Gmap+LocationsLatIn", locationLatInData: "37.421998333333335"}
2
:
{__type: "PrincipalPortal.Gmap+LocationsLatIn", locationLatInData: "14.6360916"} It is from the database